# Converting the V2 to V3 in google map for set the markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am converting the V2 code to V3. In the below two functions, they are used the getBoundsZoomLevel function. Instead of that function how to use in google map v3.
please help.

```
function fitSpecifiedMarkers(){ 
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = markers.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition()); 
  }
  var zoomLvl = this.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds); // V2 function, not available in v3.
  if (zoomLvl > this.maximumZoom) {
      zoomLvl = this.maximumZoom;
   }
   this.map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), zoomLvl);
}

 function clusterMarker() {
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   var listen = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   // Center & zoom map to contain all map markers in cluster group when clicked
  self.map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), self.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance, for this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation you can use **Map.fitBounds(LatLngBounds)** this *"Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds."*

Comment: ok thanks. How to get the this.map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds); value to store in zoomlvl?? In the above code..